# Why is this invalid?

Tags: python, printing

This is my code

```
import math

names=('Jhon','Aidan','Bob','Nik')

people=input('Name: ')
if people is names:
    print("Get Ready")
else print("This ain't your test")
```

and print after else is invalid

Comment: so instead of if people is names type"if people in name"?

Comment: You need to see if name is in names for equating you use its like English if something is something.  If something in somethings see this somethings which is more than one you will use in if you want to fine a value is in some collection.

Comment: `in`, not `is`. You are also missing a colon after `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Use in at the place of is you need to check if the list contains that name, and missing colon after else

```
people=input('Name: ')
if people in names:
    print("Get Ready")
else:
    print("This ain't your test")
```

Comment: still says print after else is invalid

Comment: You don’t have colon after else that’s the problem